# How to calculate power for a 2-level model with two L1-predictors?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, statistical-power, conditional-variance

I am new to power analysis in multi-level models. I am looking for a possibility to do a power analysis for the following 2-level model: Y = y00 + y10*D1 + y20*D2+y01*Z +y11*D1Z+y21*D2Z.

In this model, I investigate the effect of time (D1 and D2) and an experimental condition as well as their interaction effect on my outcome variable. The time is measured three times and integrated as dummy-coded contrasts in the model (D1 and D2). The experimental condition is also dummy-coded.

I tried to work with the instruction for a power analysis in 2-level models by Trend & Schäfer (2019) (see R code attached). However, I do not know how create the conditional variances for my model and I think there must be a mistake in the model .

I would be very happy to get your advice.

Thanks a lot!

R-Code:

```
#Specifying standardized input parameters
alpha.S <- .05 #Alpha level
Size.clus <- 3 #L1 sample size
N.clus <- 200 #L2 sample size

L1_DE_standardized <- .30 #L1 direct effects
L2_DE_standardized <- .50 #L2 direct effect
CLI_E_standardized <- .50 #CLI effects
ICC <- .50 #ICC
rand.sl <- .09 #Standardized random slope

#Creating variables for power simulation in z-standardized form
#Creates a dataset with two L1-predictor x and one L2-predictor Z; all predictors are dichotomous
Size.clus <- 3 #L1 sample size
N.clus <- 200 #L2 sample size
EG<-rep(c(0,1),each=300)
x<- scale(rep(1:Size.clus))
g <- as.factor(1:N.clus)
X <- cbind(expand.grid("x"=x, "g"=g))
X <- cbind(X, EG)
X$D1<- recode(var = X$x,
recodes = "-1 = 0; 0 = 1; 1 = 0")
X$D2<- recode(var = X$x,
recodes = "-1 = 0; 0 = 0; 1 = 1")

#Adapting the standardized parameters
varL1 <- 1 #L1 variance component
varL2 <- ICC/(1-ICC) #L2 variance component
varRS1 <- rand.sl*varL1 #Random slope variance tau 11
varRS2 <- rand.sl*varL1 #Random slope variance tau 22
L1_DE <- L1_DE_standardized*sqrt(varL1) #L1 direct effect
L2_DE <- L2_DE_standardized*sqrt(varL2) #L2 direct effect
CLI_E <- CLI_E_standardized*sqrt(varRS) #CLI effect

#Creating conditional variances
#I don’t know how to calculate this conditional variance with two L1 predictor
s <- sqrt((varL1)*(1-(L1_DE_standardized^2))) #L1 variance
V1 <- varL2*(1-(L2_DE_standardized^2)) #L2 variance
rand_sl.con <- varRS1*(1-(CLI_E_standardized^2)) #Random slope variance

#Creating a population model for simulation
b <- c(0, L1_DE, L1_DE, L2_DE, CLI_E,CLI_E) #vector of fixed effects (fixed intercept, L1.1. direct, L1.2. direct, L2 direct, CLI.1 effect, CLI.2 effect)
V2 <- matrix(c(V1,0,0, 0,rand_sl.con,0, 0,0,rand_sl.con), 3) #Random effects covariance matrix with covariances set to 0
# there must be a mistake some steps before that the model doesn't work
model <- makeLmer(y ~ D1 + D2 + EG + D1:EG + D2:EG +(D1+D2 | g), fixef = b, VarCorr = V2, sigma = s, data = X) #Model creation
```